# Python loop through a range of variables

Tags: python

I have a number of variables iE: `x1` to `x10`

Now I'd like to get the content of each of them.

Is it possible to put the variable together like `xi`?
Or should I just use Lists?

Kind of lost on the Syntax here I believe!
Something like that is what im thinking of:

```
while i <= 10:
    print(test+i)
```

Comment: You need to use a list not 10 separate variables

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just use a list. You'll then be able to iterate over the elements using a [`for` loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm).

You will also be able to address the elements by index: `x[i]`. Bear in mind that list indices start from zero and not one. If the indices are not small consecutive integers, you might want to consider using a dictionary instead of a list.

Answer (score 11):

If you do not want to use lists...

```
for i in range(10):
    print(eval("x" + str(i)))
```

Answer (score 10):

```
variables = [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9]
for x in variables:
    print x
```